# T-SQL data type for 39-digit number?

Tags: t-sql, ip2location

I'm using the free IPv6 data table from [Ip2Location](https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone). The table schema is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db11_ipv6](
    [ip_from] char(39) NOT NULL,
    [ip_to] char(39) NOT NULL,
    [country_code] nvarchar(2) NOT NULL,
    [country_name] nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,
    [region_name] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    [city_name] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
    [latitude] float NOT NULL,
    [longitude] float NOT NULL,
    [zip_code] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [time_zone] nvarchar(8) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX [ip_from] ON [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db11_ipv6]([ip_from]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE INDEX [ip_to] ON [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db11_ipv6]([ip_to]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Table queries are done with a converted IPv6 address to an `IpNumber`. The provided search query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM ip2location_db11_ipv6
WHERE @IpNumber BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
```

My average query time based on a few random look ups was ~1.2 seconds. While there are `3,458,959` records in the table, this seems a bit slow to me (is it? I'm by no means a SQL guru). My first thought was to make the `ip_from` and `ip_to` columns a numeric data type, but the maximum value is `58569107375850417935858934690443427840` (39 digits), which falls outside of the maximum range for a `DECIMAL` type. Is there anything that can be done to improve the query time for this?

Comment: What database and what version?

Comment: What does the text in the csv look like? Since it's supposed to be a date, can you make it a date?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Ignore my `date` comment. I misread what the data was supposed to be. Did you follow the steps in https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/importing-ip2location-data-into-mssql-and-querying-with-vbnet-ipv6/ to pad your `IP_TO` and `IP_FROM` strings? (correcting for the table name)

Comment: What is your value and datatype of `@IPNumber`? You're doing implicit conversion with the `BETWEEN` and that would possibly impact your query time.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `BINARY(17)`, 39 decimals fits into 17 bytes. [Binary type doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017).